# Null check operator used on a null value, null safety causing many errors

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

First I had a problem that I fixed by changing `late String myName, myProfilePic, myUserName, myEmail;` to `String? myName, myProfilePic, myUserName, myEmail;`, that required me to add a null check operator (!) to to `var chatRoomId = getChatRoomIdByUsernames(myUserName, username);`, (So it changes to `var chatRoomId = getChatRoomIdByUsernames(myUserName!, username);` but then it gives me that error. Can anyone tell me what to do?
When I don't use (!) then the error on `myUserName` is `"The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'".`

Comment: You can assign some initial value to your String myName like some empty string (`String myName = ''`) or you can null-check it inside of function call like: `getChatRoomIdByUsernames(myUserName ?? '', username)` so it will pass empty string if your variable myUserName is null.

Comment: @AnteBule Then I get a new error:
```RangeError (end): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1```

Comment: That's now something else not related to your initial problem, you have some different problem in your code now.

Comment: @AnteBule Could you think of any other fix for this?

Comment: Your original problem is fixed, now you have some completely new error in your code, so it's most likely not related at all and has nothing to do with your previous error. The good thing would be to post new question with new error message along with your code.

Comment: @AnteBule The error I get, it means that String? myUserName is empty, so I'll have to give it something other than just ''

Comment: It think that you are relating to your other post from link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71263243/how-can-i-fix-rangeerror-end-invalid-value-only-valid-value-is-0-1 in which I suggested solution for that.