# How can I fix "RangeError (end): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1"?

Tags: android, flutter

The line this error is point out:

```
getChatRoomIdByUsernames(String a, String b) {
    if (a.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
      return '$b\_$a';
    } else {
      return '$a\_$b';
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `substring(0,1)` throws that error only if either of your string is empty, so you can check for empty string first and return from function if it's empty, or check your passing strings before calling your function and call it only if both strings are not empty.

Comment: @AnteBule I'm sorry I'm very new to flutter I didn't understand what you meant

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in dartpad but am not able to share it, so I'll just paste it here.

```
void main() {
  String myUserName = '';
  String username = '';
  
  // you can either check for empty strings here or inside of your getChatRoomIdByUsernames function
  if(myUserName.isEmpty || username.isEmpty) {
    print('username(s) cannot be empty, please fill them.');
  } else {
   getChatRoomIdByUsernames(myUserName, username);
  }
}

getChatRoomIdByUsernames(String a, String b) {
  // checking for empty strings inside of this function
  if(a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) {
    print('username(s) cannot be empty, please fill them.');
    return;
  }
  if (a.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0) > b.substring(0, 1).codeUnitAt(0)) {
    return '$b\_$a';
  } else {
    return '$a\_$b';
  }
}
```